# CN1: Change background color of content in tab

Tags: java, codenameone

So I have this piece of code:

```
//Tabs for filter
    Tabs t = new Tabs();
    Style s = UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("Tab");
    FontImage icon1 = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_QUESTION_ANSWER, s);
    t.addTab("All", icon1, conOrders);
    //t.addTab("Done", icon1, conOrdersCompleted);
    t.addTab("Processing", icon1, conOrdersProcessing);
    this.add(t);
    initGuiBuilderComponents(resourceObjectInstance);
```

Now I want to change the background color of the content tab. Now it looks like this:

[image: Tab with color]

I want that the background of the red area is white. I am using the new GUI builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want different colors for each tab just do stuff like:

```
conOrdersProcessing.setUIID("Tab1Background");
```

And style that accordingly. This is probably the best approach.

You can also style the various pieces of the `Tabs` container with the UIID's:

`TabbedPane`, `TabsContainer` and `Tabs`. Notice you can use the Component Inspector tool in the simulator to discover UIID's of components.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I style it accordingly?

Comment: E.g. set the `Tabs` color to white in CSS or designer

Comment: What did you do that would cause that? How did you style the UI here?

Comment: I just added a css file in the CN1 settings. Then the complete style changed.

Comment: If you add CSS is deletes the theme file. I said CSS **or** designer because I can't know what you are using. I suggest unselecting CSS in settings and restoring the old resource file from backup.

Comment: Got a backup. How can I change this with the designer? Because the Tabs are made programmatically.

Comment: Just double click the theme res and edit the styling for Tabs etc. as you would normally do.

Answer (score 1):

I am presently working on tabs from CN1, with the same idea to style the tabs individually. The code below is an adaptation from the example [here](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-customize-tabs-behavior.html).

To make it work, you need the internal css support activated, or add the UIIDs in the theme editor.

```
    Tabs tb = new Tabs() {
        @Override
        protected Component createTab(String title, Image icon) {
            SpanButton custom = new SpanButton(title);
            custom.setIcon(icon);
            custom.setUIID(title); // title of the tabs, stylable background 
            custom.setTextUIID("Tab");
            custom.setIconPosition(BorderLayout.NORTH);
            custom.setIconUIID(title);
            return custom;
        }

        @Override
        protected void setTabSelectedIcon(Component tab, Image icon) {
            ((SpanButton) tab).setPressedIcon(icon);
        }

        protected void selectTab(Component tab) {
        }

        @Override
        protected void bindTabActionListener(Component tab, ActionListener l) {
            ((SpanButton) tab).addActionListener(l);
        }
    };

    Container container1 = BoxLayout.encloseY(labelOne, labelTwo);
    Container container2 = BoxLayout.encloseY(labelThree, labelFour);

    // style the containers inside the tabs
    container1.setUIID("Tab1Background");
    container2.setUIID("Tab2Background");

    // when adding the tabs, the title matches the UIID in css style-sheet
    tb.addTab("Tab1Background", FontImage.MATERIAL_3D_ROTATION, 4, container1);
    tb.addTab("Tab2Background", FontImage.MATERIAL_ACCESSIBILITY, 4, container2);

    // css

    Tab1Background {

        background-color: red;
        text-align: center;
    }

    Tab2Background {

        background-color: yellow;
        text-align: center;
     }
```